# Laravel 5.2 - Login user after create post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i'm doing a project where ALL user can create a post and pubblic it! 
if user not logged blade enable a section with email and password to create account and post.

[image]

I would like do:

1. Creation user
2. Log user in session auth ( HERE IS MY PROBLEM, HOW CAN I DO THIS? )
3. Create Post (last point because i need user_id)

CONTROLLER

```
// if user NOT registered my form will enable email and password field -- 
            if(!null($request->input('email') && request->input('password'))) {
                // create user

                $user = new User();
                $user->name = $request->input('name');
                $user->email = $request->input('email');
                $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('name'));
                $user->save();

                // login user after create user

                HOW CAN I LOG USER AFTER CREATED ACCOUNT ???

                Thank you for your help!

                // Get ID of user created

                $get_user_id = User::where('email', '=', $request('email'))->first();

                // create post

                $post = new Post();
                $post->title = $request->input('title'); 
                $post->slug = str_slug($request->input('title'),'-'); 
                $post->country = $request->input('country'); 
                $post->zone = $request->input('zone');
                $post->phone = $request->input('phone');
                $post->address = $request->input('address');
                $post->user_id = $get_user_id->id; 
                $post->save(); 
                return redirect('/')->with('message-success', 'Post creato con successo!');

            // IF USER LOGGED

            }else{
                $post = new Post();
                $post->title = $request->input('title'); 
                $post->slug = str_slug($request->input('title'),'-'); 
                $post->country = $request->input('country'); 
                $post->zone = $request->input('zone');
                $post->phone = $request->input('phone');
                $post->address = $request->input('address');
                $post->user_id = $request->input('user_id'); 
                $post->save(); 
                return redirect('/')->with('message-success', 'Post creato con successo!');
            }
```

Comment: Maybe `Auth::login($user);` ?

Comment: yes it work! but i need add a class "use Auth;"

Comment: reply the questions, i will give the ok! thank you!

Comment: Thanks, but no need. You can use function too `auth()->login($user);`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

`Auth::login($user);`

[Check out the doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

Answer (score 1):

Is not so clear what you want to do here, the way you get the user id is insecure.
I'll recommend you to use $user = Auth::user(); instead to get the user id, ($user->id).

to check the login manually use

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {}
```

so in your example I'll do something like:

```
    if (!Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
       // create User
    } else {
       // $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    }

    // finally create post
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a __construct() method to your class, and add following code:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

**And it must actually work**